# PHP MAMP and server conflicts

Tags: php, command-line-interface, mamp

I have a page that calls a php script. On MAMP everything works fine but when I upload it to a server I get the following error:

```
Call Request failed! Status code: 4000
Reason - Caught an HttpRequestValidationException due to some bad characters in the request. Make sure your post request is encoded as xml, preferable as UTF-8 ('Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8'). Exception: A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (<?xml version="..."utf-8"?> <uclassify xmlns="ht...").
```

Has anyone seen anything like that?

you can check it yourself [here](http://stackoverflowsearch.comeze.com/) just place a word like php or ios

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your server is validating based on the `content-type` header. It seems to want `text/xml`, whereas you are sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (which is the default for `$.ajax`).

Try explicitly setting the content type to `text/xml` in your `$.ajax` call. ([reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/))

Comment: what do you mean something like that $.ajax({
type: "POST",
content-type: "Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8",
url: "questions.php",
data: {'amount': amount},

Comment: Something like this : `$.ajax({ type: "POST", content-type: "text/xml; charset=UTF-8", /*etc, etc*/`

Comment: Did you just copy-paste exactly what I typed? All you have to do is ad d the `content-type` field with the value `"text/xml; charset=UTF-8"`.

Comment: ok fixed it. its contenttype not content-type but i get the same error! no change!

Comment: Try `contentType` instead of `contenttype`. I believe it's case-sensitive.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15020/discussion-between-gordon-bailey-and-mpampinos-holmens)

Comment: ohhh now i get no error but the response is an empty array like Array ( )

Answer (score 1):

try changing `charset=utf-8` to `charset=UTF-8`